# How to add columns to <asp:Table>

Tags: asp.net

I have an  on a .aspx I can add rows and cells to it but I don't seem to be able to add a column, Is there a way to do this? both these appear in the same column, sometimes I can get it to place controls where I want, sometimes not. There seems to be no ryme or reason to it?

```
            <asp:Table ID="tblMain" runat="server" Height="49px" width="1095px">
                <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Client</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="311px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtClient" runat="server" Width="311px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">E-Mail</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
           </asp:Table>
```

Comment: an `<asp:Table />` just renders as an HTML `<table>` which consists of rows (`<tr>`) and cells (`<td>`). There are no column elements, just rows and cells. The cells are pretty much your columns.

Comment: zgood Thanks for your assistance!